# How to Deploy Angular to IIS and access the app by domain name rather than domain and app name

Tags: angular

I am able to deploy apps to IIS without problems and without creating additional redirects within a web config file.

How do I deploy the app so that I do not have to specify the app name at the end of the domain?

So instead of this: maywebsite.com/myAngularApp
I am attempting to simply enter the domain: maywebsite.com

Currently I am deploying like this:
Build: `ng build --prod --base-href /my-app/` then create an App in IIS with matching name and copy files.

I this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figure this out.
It's amazing how this is hardly mentioned on the web.

I simply build without using an app name:
Then rather then deploying to IIS as an App on an existing website, I simply deployed as a Website.

In a nutshell, if you want to deploy your app to IIS without using the app name and to call the app with a domain name, then just deploy as a website.